# select2 jquery conflict in magento2

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, jquery-select2, magento2

I am creating small site using  magento 2 .  by default magento 2 comes with jquery . and i have another jquery version for the js code i have written. i am using select2 library for dropdowns.

i have budled jquery(the one i am using) , select2 library and my js code into one file called app.js and included in magento 2 app.

the problem is select 2 library not using the jquery(mine) , instead it is using the built in jquery version of magento 2. so i am getting select2 function undefined error in my code.

i have found select2 is loading the jquery in following way.

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
```

so i guess its getting the jquery through amd module which is loading built in jquery. any solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: why are you using 2 instances of jquery?

Comment: remove the added jquery, place the select2 library after jquery